# Scoped application request for Microsoft Graph, in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, authentication, microsoft-graph-api

Ive been researching the MS Graph API lately, and I'm running into a problem. My use case is that I want to read a certain mailbox's mail, and send mail for that mailbox. The mailbox is a non user related box, and is used as a service account for emails.

Ive found 2 possible flows for getting into that mailbox. The user authenticated flow, and the application (and admin consented) flow. For the application, I want to read the emails in the background in a NodeJS app, without user interaction.

When I look into the user consented flow, I find that to make it work the user HAS to log in atleast once, by hand, and consent to some stuff I want to do. I found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user) page, on how this works, and made it work in my NodeJS app. The problem is, when using this flow, I have to login BY HAND atleast once after starting my NodeJS app. Afterwards I can use the refresh token to refresh the access token, but I dont want to do the login by hand.

The second option, and most suitable option for my NodeJS app, is the application flow. I found [this](https://medium.com/@fiqriismail/how-to-get-an-access-token-for-microsoft-graph-api-using-node-js-258723f29cc6) tutorial on how to do that, and I made it all work. I fetch a token, and that token grants me access to the box via the Graph API.

But using the application flow, I found that I have to have the roles (i.e.): "User.ReadAll, Mail.Read, Mail.Send". This gives my application rights to read and send mail FOR ALL users in the account.. Which is WAY too much overkill for my situation.

Now my question; Is there a way for me to use MS Graph, with the application authentication flow, but without having access to all users' mailboxes, only to my specific account I want to read?

Thanks in advance,
Caspar

Comment: What do you mean by all of the user's account? One email address or one credential corresponds to only one account.

Comment: Thats right, but in the application flow, you fetch an access token which is able to access ALL users, instead of just one. So then I get access to all mailboxes, which is not what I want, I want access to just one.

Comment: No. That's not how it works. It's impossible that you can access the other people's account using just one pair of credentials. Furthermore, what do you mean by other users? Other users in the same organization or what? Please clarify.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-22
If you look under application persmission, there you can see that atleast the documentation tells me so. Or am I understanding something incorrectly? There it says it will have access to all users..

Comment: .. /sigh, while reading the documentation further, at the bottom of the link I sent, it says:

Important Administrators can configure application access policy to limit app access to specific mailboxes and not to all the mailboxes in the organization, even if the app has been granted the application permissions of Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite, Mail.Send, MailboxSettings.Read, or MailboxSettings.ReadWrite.

So it is possible, and thats the answer! :)

Comment: Even with the `All` permission you are still restricted to that specific user. When it means all mailbox, it's referring to all mailbox of that specific user not all the user in the organization. I've been working with MS Graph API for a while now, at least that's what's working for me. Otherwise, it's just absurd. Like I can access all users account just by login into one.

Comment: Aviv, which authentication flow are you talking about? If you are using the delegated one, then thats correct. I am talking specifically about the application auth flow here, which makes it different I think. Either way, for now this issue can be resolved by setting up these application access policies.

Answer (score 0):

While linking the documentation reference, I saw that I read over the most important footnote:

Important Administrators can configure application access policy to limit app access to specific mailboxes and not to all the mailboxes in the organization, even if the app has been granted the application permissions of Mail.Read, Mail.ReadWrite, Mail.Send, MailboxSettings.Read, or MailboxSettings.ReadWrite.

So it is possible using the application access policies.